# Function returning Object rather than Array

Tags: php, arrays, database, mysqli

I have created a DB query within a function with the view for it to return an array which I can use in multiple instances later.

However, when I call the function it is returning an Object ("Events Object ( [Database] => mysqli Object") rather than the array that I planned.

I know that the query is working as if 'print_r($events)' rather than 'return $events' within the function itself I can see all the result info as expected.

```
public function get_events()
    {

        $stmt = $this->Database->prepare("SELECT 'id', `title`, `event_desc`, `date`, `time`, `location`, `spots`, `event_city`, `event_spots_available`, `event_series` FROM `events` ORDER BY `date` ASC");
        $stmt->execute();      

        $events = array();  

        /* bind variables to prepared statement */
        $stmt->bind_result($col1, $col2, $col3, $col4, $col5, $col6, $col7, $col8, $col9, $col10);


        /* fetch values */
        while ($stmt->fetch()) 
        {
            $events[] = array(
                'event_id'              => $col1,
                'event_title'           => $col2,
                'event_desc'            => $col3,
                'event_date'            => $col4,
                'event_time'            => $col5,
                'event_location'        => $col6,
                'event_spots'           => $col7,
                'event_city'            => $col8,
                'event_spots_available' => $col9,
                'event_series'          => $col10 
            );

        }
        $stmt->close();
        return $events;
    }
```

}

Please advise on my mistake?

Comment: If you have a database query the result will always be an object. If you want to use this object, you can fetch the result as array or each row as an array on its own. http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php This should help. If you want, I can give you an example of a "query-result" and how to transform this into an array (entire working example) Let me know if this is what you need.

Comment: Incorrect quotes around `id`, it should be `SELECT \`id\`, \`title\`, ...`

Comment: Please check what is in events bariable by this print_r($events);

Answer (score 0):

If you use prepared statements and want the result as an array, I would recommend something like this:

```
$query= "SELECT * FROM events;";
if($stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $query))
{
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $param);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $resultObject = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}

$myArray = array();
$size = mysqli_num_rows($resultObject);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
{
    $myArray[$i] = mysqli_fetch_array($resultObject, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```